# Вопрос по классам

Tags: вёрстка, css

Подскажите, в чем разница:"`class1 .class2`" (контекстные классы) и "`.class1.class2`"(???)
И что и когда лучше использовать?

Comment: первая запись указывает на содержание одного элемента в другом, вторая - на наличие обоих классов у одного элемента.

Comment: @Etki, то есть, вторая запись сработает, только если элементт будет иметь строго эти два класса? Например, `<div class="class1 class2>` сработает для второй записи (и для первой тоже), а `<div class=class2>` сработает только для первой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запись .class1 .class2 будет применена к блоку с классом class2, который лежит внутри class1:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2"></div>
</div>
```

Вторая запись будет применена к блоку, который сразу имеет два класса - class1 и class2:

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```